# Have only Tuesdays and Fridays repeating

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to drag a repeating pattern of Tuesdays and Fridays repeating in Google Sheets? The type of output I'm looking for would be this:

> Tuesday, June 2, 2015
>   Friday, June 5, 2015
>   Tuesday, June 9, 2015
>   Friday, June 12, 2015
>   ...

*and then drag down to continue the pattern...*
When I do it now, it continues incrementing by he number of days *between* Tuesday and Friday.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try a formula:

```
=query(ArrayFormula({(date(2015,6,2)+row(A1:A1000)-1), weekday(date(2015,6,2)+row(A1:A1000)-1,2)}), "select Col1 where Col2 matches '"&JOIN("|", 2, 5)&"' limit 10")
```

where the date() function holds the starting date
and the limit part limits the output to whatever number you want.
See if that works ?

EDIT: If you only want the tuesdays and fridays from the list of dates in col A, try:

```
=filter(A2:A, (WEEKDAY(A2:A)=3)+(WEEKDAY(A2:A)=6))
```

Then copy the output and paste in col A as 'values only'.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand... Are you suggesting that be the formula for the date field only - because it puts (meaningless?) values in the two columns to the right of it, too.

Comment: What is your locale ? can you share an example spreadsheet here ?

Comment: It is only Column A (the dates) that I am trying to change --- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TDoAAxQiaJyrvCja0-nmh20TUWM8PaK3LbAZ1JB8L1s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If you only want the tuesdays and fridays from the list of dates in col A, try: =filter(A2:A, (WEEKDAY(A2:A)=3)+(WEEKDAY(A2:A)=6)) --> also see cell E2 in the sheet you shared. Then copy the output and paste in col A as 'values only'.

Comment: Actually, on second thought... What I need isn't a date column based on a date column; it's a date column based on "itself." I just need an "independent" column of dates. Could you please tell me how I could populate Column F in that same sheet - but not based on anything else - just starting from some given date (a Tuesday or Friday) and incrementing from there? Thank you again!!!

Comment: That is exactly what my first formula did. just replace the date() part with the date you want to start with. The limit10 at the end controls how many rows will be outputted (10 with the present formula).

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that. I'm still having a problem. It's starting from a strange date - not one that I've indicated in the formula. I updated the sheet. Please feel free to modify the sheet itself - it's just a copy. Thank you so much - I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Try this: =query(ArrayFormula({((A13+1)+row(A1:A)-1), weekday((A13+1)+row(A1:A)-1,2)}), "select Col1 where Col2 matches '"&JOIN("|", 2, 5)&"' limit 100")